# How can I set a default JSON when swagger ui will not be able to fetch from URL?

Tags: json, default, swagger

How can I set a default JSON when swagger ui will not be able to fetch from URL? For example I am proving URL http://www.mysite.com/userData this URL should return swagger compatible JSON but in case of any error like connection problem, if it fails to fetch data from that URL then I want to display a default JSON. How can I do it?